# How do I use php rename across servers

Tags: php, server, rename, hosts

I need to move a file from one server to another using PHP. What is the proper syntax for this? Everything I have tried has failed, yet I know permissions are correct. I believe it should be something like:

```
rename('//server1.host.com/folder/file.txt','//server2.host.com/folder/file.txt');
```

I am trying this on Windows 2012 servers and have access to everything.

The web server running this code currently has the file on it, I'm trying to move the file to another host.

Comment: This is not possible. The function _renames_ (moves) a file _within_ the local file system. You need something like `scp` or similar to move a file to another system. PHPs `ssh2://` wrapper allows this. The issue is the writing on the remote side. You certainly _can_ use `rename()` to move ("download") a file to the local system. But you need write access on the remote system for moving a file there ("upload") which is something more complex. You need a login for that.

Comment: I understand why this wouldn't work and wouldn't have asked the question except I've _seen_ it work. Does it make a difference that everything is on a local network? We use rename in another project to do this and it works. I tried copying the code over to the project I am working on and it fails, so I was trying to see if anyone has had success doing this or knows something I don't to get it to work.

Comment: The type of network is irrelevant. It is a question of permission on the remote system. I suggest you simply take a look into the systems error log files to find traces of the attempts. That should give you more specific hints on why the requests fail.

Comment: It _might_ be that what you are looking for is a way to move a file between different _shares_ mounted into the local file system of your MS-Windows system. Your example URLs _might_ suggest that. In that case it is _not_ php doing the network transfer or even addressing the remote system, it is the network layer of the local operating system. That layer can indeed implement and handle the authorization issue I referred to. In shorter words: in that scenario you would actually to a _local_ moving of a file from the php point of view.

Comment: I'll take a look at the error logs. It isn't different shares; files are actually being moved between servers. One is a physical server, the other virtual and in another location, but on the local network.

Comment: So what protocol do you want to use? `//` is _not_ a valid protocol or php wrapper... See the official documentation: http://php.net/manual/en/wrappers.php

Comment: The working version we have uses `\\\\example.host.com\\path\\to\\folder` Where each \\ is an escaped \. It's just using Windows pathing. I don't necessarily have a protocol preference, the goal is just to get something working.

Comment: That definitely looks to me like MS-Windows shares. But I have little experiences with that stuff, sorry. I am afraid I can be of nu further assistance with that.